# How can I use attributes from the class above?

Tags: python, class, arguments

I made an outer class with a function to create a path of folders, user decides the path and inner class to save the plot image to that folder, user decides on file name and format. My problem is that I can't use the outer class attributes.
How can I use attributes from the class above? Is there another clean way of such a dependency?

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

# Outter class
class Folders():
    def __init__(self,
        base_path="folder_name1/folder_name2"):
        self.base_path = base_path
        pass
# Function to create path of folders
    def create(self):
        try:
            os.makedirs(self.base_path)
        except FileExistsError:
            # directory already exists
            pass
# Inner class
    class Save:
        def __init__(self,current_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y_%m_%d@%H_%M_%S'),
                     image_format = '.png',
                     image_name = '/name_of_image'):
            self.current_date = current_date
            self.image_name = image_name
# Function to save the images in the created path
        def image1(self):
            f.savefig(self.base_path+self.image_name+self.image_format, bbox_inches='tight')

# Plotting the figure
x = np.linspace(0, 6*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, 'r-')

# Creates path of folders
folder = Folders()
folder.create()

# Save images with default arguments
save = folder.Save()
save.image1()

# Save images with chosen arguments
savea = folder.Save(image_format='.jpg', image_name='image_name')
savea.image1()
```

Comment: I don't see anything called `arguments` anywhere in the code you've shown, so I have no idea what you're talking about when you say "outer class" or "the class above".

Comment: I have edited the program added few comments and rid of not needed part of code. How it is clearer now

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code more closely and making the **guess** that by "self.arguments" you mean "*attributes* of `self`": you seem to be under the impression that the inner class is somehow associated with the outer class, such that instances of the inner class implicitly have some instance of the outer class created along with them. In Python, this is not the case. `self.base_path` cannot resolve to the `base_path` attribute of some `Folders` instance because *`self` is not a `Folders` instance*; it is a `Save` instance, and `Save` is not a subclass of `Folders`. It is merely *defined within* `Folders`, which is merely namespacing (i.e., outside code needs to refer to the class as `Folders.Save` rather than just `Save`).

You should redesign this completely. [None of this makes sense design-wise in the first place](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0): what does it mean to say that you have "a Folders", or "a Save"? What *are* those things? Remember, "object" is a fancy word for *thing*, and "class" is a fancy word for "kind of thing".

Anyway, the natural way to provide information to an instance of a class is to *pass it to the constructor*, and then have `__init__` store that information somewhere. You know, like you are already doing when you create the `Folders` instance in the first place.